# Should ellipses be used in main/global navigation bar?

Tags: navigation, icons, menu

I was browsing the BBC website and I noticed they are using ellipsis to indicate there are more items in the main navigation than visible. I attached two screenshots, the first one is before clicking the ellipsis icon, and the second one is after clicking the ellipsis icon.

[image: Before clicking the ellipsis icon]

[image: After clicking the ellipsis icon]

Is this behavior correct? Are ellipsis used right? Is there any research in this area?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? It also helps with responsive web design - if you reduce the width of the browser then nav items come out of the primary bar and go into the ellipsis menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's debatable (and a very interesting question).

Even before [**GUI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) existed, there were indications when the system awaited a user action. These could be a blinking cursor, a square, a Y/N choice, or an ellipsis.

With the advent of GUI, these user expectations translated into the menus we see today. As most old commands shifted to menus, a best practice emerged: **menu items expecting a user action would display an ellipsis.** [See this Wikipedia entry for further detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#Usage_in_computer_system_menus).

To illustrate this, consider the images below:

## Pre GUI

[image]

Old UNIX screen with blinking square

[image]

Old UNIX screen with ellipsis

## GUI menus

[image]

Old Windows Start menu

[image]

Old MacOS menu (By Self-made software screenshot, Fair use, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=23639135)

[image]

My current Firefox menu

[image]

My current Photoshop menu

**As you might notice, commands leading to subsequent actions often show an ellipsis.** Conversely, if a command completes with the selection, it lacks an ellipsis.

**Why do I mention this?** Because *technically*, the BBC page is incorrect. There's no action; the three dots could be merely decorative or a glitch.

## But...

The BBC has a reputable UX team, likely having tested this extensively. So, while *"in theory"* it's incorrect, **if it works for users, it's right**, it's the basis of [User Centered Design (UCD)](https://dorve.com/blog/ux/human-centered-design-user-centered-design/). A few years ago, [hamburger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) and [kebab menus](https://uxpickle.com/know-your-menu-hamburger-vs-kebab/) were considered design heresies. Now, they're among the most common and recognized UI patterns.

Personally, I'd have used a kebab or an arrow, or group menu items differently. Then again, I didn't test it and I'm pretty sure they did.

**In short:** *No, it's not technically correct. But whether it's wrong can only be determined through testing.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, it's a very detailed and useful explanation.